# Cascading Dropdown issue with Angular FormArrays

Tags: angular

I am having an Angular app, in this App I used FormArrays. inside that FormArray I am having Cascading dropdown.

in this Cascading dropdown, I used `(selectionChange)="func"`, this will be the reason for the cascading dropdown.

```
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-label>Holding type</mat-label>
                                        <mat-select formControlName="hodingTypeFH"
                                            (selectionChange)="GetHoldingNameById($event)">
                                           
                                            <mat-option [value]="type.id" *ngFor="let type of holdingTypeList">
                                                {{type.holdingType}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-label>Holding Name</mat-label>
                                        <mat-select formControlName="holdingNameFH">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let name of hodlingNameList"
                                                [value]="name.id">{{name.holdingName}}</mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
```

in its code behind file(TS) file

GetHoldingNameById(event: any) {

```
this.familyHoldingSevice.getHoldingNameByHoldingTypeId(Number(event.value)).subscribe(names => {
  this.hodlingNameList = names;

})
```

}
now in the output

here both dropdowns show the same value, which means here livestock data showing in both dropdowns.

Comment: not able to post the image here